# DbDataReader returns null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure to get 1 row out of a table.

```
    spGetDepartment
    @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [ID],[Name],[Description]
    FROM tblDepartments
    WHERE [ID] = @ID

END
```

When stored procedure is tested in SQL I get the desired result.

When I try to call the stored procedure from code (C#) and debug the page I can see the reader gets populated correctly but when trying to read it, it changes to null value.
Here is the code calling the stored procedure.

```
public static Department GetDepartment(string ID)
    {
        Department Dept = new Department();

        DbCommand comm = DataAccess.CreateCommand();
        try
        {
            comm.CommandText = "spGetDepartment";
            // create a new parameter
            DbParameter _ID = comm.CreateParameter();
            _ID.ParameterName = "@ID";
            _ID.Value = ID;
            _ID.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            comm.Parameters.Add(_ID);
            comm.Connection.Open();
            DbDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read()) 
            {
                Dept.DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"].ToString());
                Dept.DepartmentName = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                Dept.Description = rdr["Description"].ToString();
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.LogError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            comm.Dispose();
            comm.Connection.Close();
        }
        return Dept;
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that `rdr["ID"]` is returning null? Or something else?

Comment: When the debugger gets to the line While(rdr.read()) it goes to the rdr.close() step. it will not step into the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    reader.Read();
    Dept.DepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"].ToString());
    Dept.DepartmentName = rdr["Name"].ToString();
    Dept.Description = rdr["Description"].ToString();
    reader.Close();
}
else
{ //No data
}
```

Comment: This did the trick I changed the while statement to a if statement like you showed above. Thank you very much.